# What is the minimum input length required for sql injection?

Tags: postgresql, security

Perhaps this belongs on the 'golf code' stack or elsewhere, if so, apologies and I'll remove it.

I have been working on a older application and re-writing SQL statements as postgres functions to help avoid exposure to SQL injection. I got to thinking, that if something was in the form of

`SELECT * FROM Whatever WHERE id = user_input_here`

then what would be the shortest `user_input_here` that could allow Bobby Tables or one of his friends to do their dirty work? If the user_input string had already been constrained to a very few characters, presumably no mischief could be done. (Perhaps we know the 'id' is always exactly 6 characters.) Presumably you'd want at least one dummy character for the original query, then a semicolon before your injected code, what could be the shortest valid statement after that?

Understand that I am not advocating this as a protection method, I'm just curious.

Comment: I’m not sure I understand the point of this. Protecting yourself from SQL Injection is a best practice to ensure business continuity. I don’t understand the obsession with finding ways to work around it and be lazy by assuming that constraining the length in *very specific cases* might be “good enough.” I’m not going to close the question just yet but I think the premise is terrible.

Comment: @AaronBertrand come on, he said he's just curious. what's wrong with that? :-)

Comment: @fileprem I'm curious about how many nails my run-flat tires can absorb before they become non-run-flats, but that doesn't make it a good idea to pour nails all over my driveway, or make it on-topic here. The OP even suggests in the opener does not belong here.

Comment: I have found a discussion of this here:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/152606/is-there-a-field-length-that-is-too-short-to-allow-harmful-sql-injection/152617

Comments point out that in a legacy application one may have to prioritize one's effort in correcting existing flaws and a few situations where parameterized query may not be possible/practical. Perhaps this question would have caused less offense if I had simply asked "what is the shortest valid SQL?". 

I am not able to delete this question myself, since it has an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Probably one of the shortest injections are used by [sqlmap](http://sqlmap.org/), for example: "`union select version();`" (note the leading space).

I can't think of anything shorter than `';call boom()--` - which exploits multiple-query feature of [LibPQ](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-exec.html#LIBPQ-EXEC-MAIN), and - obviously - requires top-secret application-specific knowledge.

This code is exploitable:

```
import sys
import psycopg2
conn = psycopg2.connect(dsn='')
cur = conn.cursor()
sql = "SELECT reltuples, relpages FROM pg_class WHERE relname = '{}'".format(sys.argv[1])
cur.execute(sql)
for row in cur:
    print(row)
```

Exploited:

```
$ python exploitable.py pg_class
(342.0, 12)
$ python exploitable.py "';call boom()--"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exploitable.py", line 6, in <module>
    cur.execute(sql)
psycopg2.InternalError: Boom!
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function boom() line 1 at RAISE
```